# Spring 3.2 Web MVC @ModelAttribute without label

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am trying to get Spring 3.2 MVC to return a JSON response without the default label.

For example,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dt")
public class DTAgentsController {

@ModelAttribute
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;UTF-8")
    public DTResponse agents() {
        DTResponse resp = new DTResponse();
        resp.setsEcho(1);
        resp.setiTotalDisplayRecords(10);
        resp.setiTotalRecords(50);
        return resp;
    }
}
```

returns

```
{"DTResponse":{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":50,"iTotalDisplayRecords":10}}
```

I just want the JSON output to be

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":50,"iTotalDisplayRecords":10}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not `@ModelAttribute`, it just means what data that you want to store or get from model. It seems that you use jQuery datatables, so you should add **`@ResponseBody`** to the method `agents()`.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
    public DTResponse agents() {
        DTResponse resp = new DTResponse();
        resp.setsEcho(1);
        resp.setiTotalDisplayRecords(10);
        resp.setiTotalRecords(50);
        return resp;
    }
}
```